# One-line multiple variable value assignment with an "if" condition

Tags: python

It is possible to assign values to multiple variables.

```
a, b = 5, 10
```

I need to assign those values based on a condition and I tried,

```
a, b = 1, 1 if c == 1 else 5, 10
```

It resulted a `ValueError`.

> ValueError: too many values to unpack

I tried with two conditions for each and it was a success.

```
a, b = 1 if c == 1 else 5, 1 if c == 1 else 10
```

But I need to achieve this using a single `if` condition, single line. I know this reduces the readability. But still is it possible? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can acheive this by putting `(a, b)` in parentheses.

```
a, b = (1, 1) if c == 1 else (5, 10)
```

The current code is equivalent to

```
a, b = 1, (1 if c == 1 else 5), 10
```

Which gives a value error as you are trying to unpack a 3-tuple into two variables.

Answer (score 6):

You could also index based using the result of `c == 1`:

```
a, b = ((5, 10), (1, 1))[c == 1]
```

The result of `c == 1` will either be `True -> 1` or `False  -> 0` so we will end up taking `(1, 1)` i.e index `1` if the condition evaluates to True or `(5, 10)` i.e `0` if it is False.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
a, b = ((a, b) if c == 1 else (5, 10))
```

**or this**

```
a, b = (a, b) if c == 1 else (5, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with vectors, you can also use numpy.

```
import numpy as np
condition = np.arange(10) > 5
x = np.ones(10)
y = np.zeros(10)

(a,b) = np.where(condition, (x,y), (y,x))

print(a)
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
print(b) 
[1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```